# Send Data from form to another Page using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

```
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template
    import requests
    import numpy as np
    import joblib
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html')



    
    @app.route('/nexthome')
    def nexthome():
        return render_template('nexthome.html')
    
    @app.route("/predict", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    
    def predict():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.form.get('age'))
            try:
                total_training = float(request.form.get("total_training"))
                age = float(request.form.get('age'))
                length_of_service = float(request.form.get("length_of_service"))
                KPI = float(request.form.get("KPI"))
                awards_won = float(request.form.get("awards_won"))
                avg_training_score = float(request.form.get("avg_training_score"))
                previous_year_rating = float(request.form.get("previous_year_rating"))
                department_Analytics = float(request.form.get("department_Analytics"))
                department_Finance = float(request.form.get("department_Finance"))
                department_HR = float(request.form.get("department_HR"))
                department_Legal = float(request.form.get("department_Legal"))
                department_Operations = float(request.form.get("department_Operations"))
                department_Procurement = float(request.form.get("department_Procurement"))
                department_R = float(request.form.get("department_R"))
                department_Sales_Marketing = float(request.form.get("department_Sales_Marketing"))
                department_Technology = float(request.form.get("department_Technology"))
                education_level_Bachelor = float(request.form.get("education_level_Bachelor"))
                education_level_Below_Secondary = float(request.form.get("education_level_Below_Secondary"))
                education_level_Master = float(request.form.get("education_level_Master"))
                gender_f = float(request.form.get("gender_f"))
                gender_m = float(request.form.get("gender_m"))
                arguments = [total_training, age, length_of_service, KPI, awards_won, avg_training_score, previous_year_rating, department_R,
                            department_Analytics, department_Sales_Marketing, department_Finance, department_HR, department_Legal, department_Operations, department_Procurement,
                            department_Technology, education_level_Bachelor, education_level_Below_Secondary, education_level_Master, gender_f, gender_m]
                pred_arg = np.array(arguments)
                pred_arg = pred_arg.reshape(1, -1)
                load_model = open("decision_model.pkl", "rb")
                model = joblib.load(load_model)
                prediction = model.predict(pred_arg)
    
            except ValueError:
                return "Please Checked the Value Entered and Try again Cheers"
    
        return render_template("predict.html", final_prediction = prediction)
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
    
 home.html
<form action="/nexthome" method='GET'>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="gender_m"><p class="font-weight-bold">Male</p></label>
                        <input type="text" name="gender_m">
                        <small id="gender_mHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter 1 if employee belong to this gender </small>
                        </div>
 <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Next'>
 </form>     

nexthome.html
<form method="POST" action="/predict">
<div class="form-group">
              <label for='age'><p class="font-weight-bold">age</p></label>
              <input type="text" name='age'>
              <small id="ageHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the Age of the Employee</small></br>
              </div>
 <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Submit'>
                        
</form>
```

Hi everyone am trying to deploy an app using flask, the app is supposed to retrieve data from the form on two pages, but i dont know how to i can do that, am able to navigate from the homepage to the next page, but it seems am not able to pass the data to the next page, and be able to display the result in another page, right now am stuck i have tried everything I can't get it to work.
any help, please.

Comment: <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name =“submit1” id =“submit1” value='Submit'>
<input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name =“submit2” id =“submit2” value='Submit'>, in python: if resquest.form.get(“submit1”):